# Numerical integration of array with array value as upper limit

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

So I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.special as spec
import scipy.integrate as integrate

a = array
b = constant * a
c = b*a/constant
e3 = spec.expn(3,c)
```

Now, I need to compute the integral for **e3** going from **0** to **a**. Since **e3** is a function of **c** which in turn is a function of **a** I'm having a hard time solving this one.
I've tried using a *loop*, *integrate.quad* or *both* in order to solve this but I keep getting all sorts of errors.
I'm pretty new at integrating sutff in python so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You write that `a` is an array, therefore `c` is also an array. What do you mean then by "going from 0 to a"? What sort of errors do you get?

Comment: Could you explain me in math notation what you want to compute please?  I know that expn(n, x) computes an integral from 1 to infty, it is not the exponential function.

Comment: @RecencyEffect  Some of the errors I got during my various tries (while calling the quad function) are 'TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars' or 'ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()'.

Comment: @agus.dinamarca The math notation would be $\int_{0}^{a} \Epsilon_3(c) da$.

I should add that I tried iterrating over the values of the arrays before integration, but maybe that's the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a possible solution, check if I understand the problem correctly and if it is useful...

```
import scipy.special as spec
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np

array = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])  # array[i] >= 0 for all i in [0, len(array) - 1]. For example, array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
constant = 3 # >= 0. For example, constant = 3


a = array
b = constant * a # multiply numpy array by a scalar (it is possible with numpy arrays (: )
c = b * a / constant

e3 = spec.expn(3, c)

# Some usefull explanations:

print('Output:', e3) # return a ndarray with the value of the integral e3 en each point specified in c (numpy array)
# Output: [1.09691967e-01 2.76136095e-03 1.04786279e-05 5.96855753e-09 4.97790975e-13]

# For evaluate the integral e3 from 0 to a[len(a) - 1]:
result1 = e3[len(a) - 1] - e3[0] 
print('Output:', result1)
# Output: -0.499999999950223

# Other thing is the integral of e3 from 0 to a[len(a) - 1]. You can use quad (return the value and an estimted error)
# See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html
result2 = quad(lambda x: spec.expn(3, x), 0, c[len(a) - 1])
print('Output:', result2)
# Output: (0.3333333333328521, 4.440892098500626e-16)

# Note that integration limits are floats not arrays.
```

Comment: Yeah, this works well enough.

Now, if we were to expand on this a bit: say that this time I take the result from **spec.expn(3,c)** (which will be an array) I multiply it by another array **d** and I want to integrate it from **0 to a**. How does one go about doing that?

Comment: That would be multiplying two arrays (they have to have the same size), you could do it with numpy.multiply(d, spec.expn(3,x)). However, there is an exception when you want to integrate. I would have to analyse better why it happens...